# XSD regroup schemas

Tags: c#, xsd

I've the following schemated XSD :

**schema1.xsd**

```
<schema xmlns="D" 
        targetNamespace="A">

    <import namespace="B" schemaLocation="schema3.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="C" schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>
...
</schema>
```

**schema2.xsd**

```
<schema xmlns="C" 
        targetNamespace="C">
    <import namespace="B" schemaLocation="schema3.xsd"/>
    ...
</schema>
```

**schema3.xsd**

```
<schema targetNamespace="B">
    ...
</schema>
```

These 3 files are in one directory (`D:\temp\`). I can load 'schema1.xsd', but C# doesn't know where are the two others. I have to write

```
schemaLocation="D:\temp\schema2.xsd"
schemaLocation="D:\temp\schema3.xsd"
```

and it's on.

And I want to keep my relatives link.
How can I regroup them in one file ?

Comment: You need to add the code that shows how you're loading the XSDs. .NET knows how to load the schemas exactly the way you've described it, as long as your initial schema is loaded **with** a base URI.

Comment: I can add the others schemas to my 'XmlReaderSettings' object with their uri and it works. But how to append them to make only one file ?

Comment: In the "common" world, that includes .NET, you can't combine XSDs that target different namespaces, in a single file. The closest you might get to what you want is to put them inside the types section of a WSDL file, but that's a whole different conversation. Oh, in general you shouldn't be doing what you implied with the settings...